# How to resume scp with partially copied files?

Tags: bash, rsync, scp, resume

I'm using the `scp` shell command to copy huge folder of files.

But at some point in time I had to kill the running command (by Ctrl+C or kill).

To my understanding `scp` copies files sequentially, so there should be only one partially copied file.

**How can same scp command be resumed to not overwrite successfully copied files and to properly handle partially copied files?**

P.S. I know I can do this kind of stuff in rsync, but scp is faster for me for some reason and I use it instead.

Comment: I suspect rsync is slower because it spends some extra time doing things that permit you to restart a transfer. You might consider just using rsync to finish the partial transfer.

Comment: If you wanna be clever, you can always try `dd` with a proper `skip` variable, and pipe to `ssh` :)

Comment: This is off-topic for SO. It belongs on SuperUser, and indeed [has been asked there](https://superuser.com/questions/561658/how-can-i-resume-a-large-scp-file-transfer-when-using-port-forwarding).

Comment: rsync uses ssh by default under the covers `Typically, rsync is configured to use ssh by default` so...it should be about as fast (though it does a directory listing first, which may give a slower start)

Answer (score 307, accepted):

You should use `rsync` over `ssh`

```
rsync -P -e ssh remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/path /local/path
```

The key option is **`-P`**, which is the same as `--partial --progress`

> By default, rsync will delete any partially transferred file if the transfer is interrupted. In some circumstances it is more desirable to keep partially transferred files. Using the --partial option tells rsync to keep the partial file which should make a subsequent transfer of the rest of the file much faster.

Other options, such `-a` (for archive mode), and `-z` (to enable compression) can also be used.

The manual: https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html

Comment: Just wanted to note that rsync will resume a batch copy started with scp just fine.

Comment: You'll get "skipping directory ." error, unless you also specify `-r`. Source: http://lucasb.eyer.be/snips/rsync-skipping-directory.html

Comment: Worked for me, but I added --append too.... 


rsync -P --append -e ssh remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/path /local/path

Comment: @CraigAnderson that is the important point that has been left out. The answer sounds like it is suggesting the download should have started with rsync to begin with.

Comment: The options given in the answer did not work for me, but this did : `rsync -P -rsh remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/path /local/path`

Comment: You can add options to the ssh commad. I was able to resume an scp copy through a jumpbox with: `rsync -r -P -e 'ssh -J jumpuser@jumphost' /local/path remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/path`

Comment: Sorry, but I can't seem to get this to work for me. My ssh is on port 2222, and I'm using an RSA key to access it. I've tried a few different permutations of the following but keep getting "Permission denied":  `rsync -r -P -e 'ssh -p 2222 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa' remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/path /local/path`. Anything I should check or change to get this to work?

Comment: I googled how to rsync over ssh. but people said "use scp, not rsync.. it is not possible" ok now I googled how to resume scp transfers, now I found the solution for rsync via ssh -.-

Comment: The `-e ssh` shouldn't be necessary as rsync uses SSH by default...Sadly there's no -P option in BSD/OS ...

Comment: Symobic links were not copied. Shows `not a regular file`. Any way to copy that also?

Comment: What if I am on a server I can't `sudo` in to install `rsync`? Say, a computing cluster?

Comment: I'm on a mac and when I ran with `--rsh` I get an error "rsync: Failed to exec shh: No such file or directory (2)" I had to provide the full path of ssh for some reason. `rsync --verbose -P --recursive --rsh $(which shh) ...`

Comment: It looks like `-e ssh` is not needed.

Comment: my scp command:
scp -r /local/path remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/path 

translated to (so I didn't get an error): 
rsync -P -e ssh /local/path/ remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/path 

beware the trailing slash at the end of the local path which is needed in case your dir is not empty.

Answer (score 56):

An alternative to rsync:

Use `sftp` with option `-r` (recursively copy entire directories) and option `-a` of `sftp`'s `get` command "resume partial transfers of existing files."

**Prerequisite:** Your `sftp` implementation has already a `get` with `-a` option.

**Example:**

Copy directory `/foo/bar` from remote server to your local current directory. Directory `bar` will be created in your local
current directory.

```
echo "get -a /foo/bar" | sftp -r user@remote_server
```

Comment: Your solution is great because my server doesn't allow login in ssh, so rsync doesn't work. I needed to upload instead of download so here is my command: `echo "put -a foo/bar" | sftp -r server:/foo`

Comment: This seems much viable option for resuming partially downloaded files, because rsync does not seem to be much ssh friendly (with non-default ports).

Comment: This also works on Windows, no rsync needed

Comment: @codezombie try rsync -P -e "ssh -p 2022" remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/path /local/path to access ssh over port 2022, etc. you can also pass any other ssh option like this.

Answer (score 29):

Since OpenSSH 6.3, you can use [`reget` command](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#reget) in `sftp`.

It has the same syntax as the `get`, except that it starts a transfer from the end of an existing local file.

```
echo "reget /file/path" | sftp -r user@server_name
```

The same effect has `-a` switch to the [`get` command](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#get) or [global command-line `-a` switch of `sftp`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#a).

Answer (score 11):

Another possibility is to try to salvage the scp you've already started when it stalls.

ctrl+z to background and stop it, then ssh over to the receiving server and login, then exit. Now fg the scp process and watch it resume from 'stalled'!

Comment: Worked for me on Mac OS X.  Thanks for posting this, it saved my bacon today!

Comment: Kick that network to see if it revives itself :)

Comment: Can also do the second ssh connection from a different terminal, instead of `CTRL+Z` and `fg`.

Comment: Works great for an in-progress `scp` that stalled. TY!

Answer (score 8):

When rsync stalls as well after couple of seconds when initially running fine I ended up with the following brute force solution to start and stop an re-start the download every 60s:

```
cat run_me.sh
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]
do
  rsync --partial --progress --rsh=ssh user@host:/path/file.tgz file.tgz &
  TASK_PID=$!
  sleep 60
  kill $TASK_PID
  sleep 2
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `-rsh` and `-P` options of `rsync`. `-P` is for partial download and `-rsh` indicates transfer is over ssh procotol.

The complete command would be : 
`rsync -P -rsh remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/path /local/path`

Comment: Same as jordi's answer?

Comment: Which version of rsync is this for? My relatively modern version (rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31), doesn't have a `-rsh` option with a single dash, only `--rsh=COMMAND` which the manual says is a synonym for `-e  COMMAND`

Answer (score -7):

I got the same issue yesterday, transfering a huge sql dump over via scp, I got lucky with `wget --continue the_url`

That blog post explains it quite well
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/wget-resume-broken-download.html basically:

```
wget --continue url
```

Comment: It's considered best practice to copy the relevant parts from a url into the answer incase the site goes down.

Comment: I'm trying to upload, so no wget for me.